# Referencing a static file in a custom command

Tags: django

I am writing a custom command in Django, and I want to reference some static files for that app. Suppose the command is at `myproject/myapp/management/commands/mycommand.py`, the static file is at `myproject/myapp/static/myapp/myfile.txt`, how do I reference `myfile.txt` from `mycommand.py`? If I use `../../../static/myapp/myfile.txt`, it does not find the file.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do it...

1. If you define `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static')` in settings.py file then you can access the static directory like

   ```
   /commands/mycommand.py
   from django.conf import settings
   pprint.pprint(settings.STATIC_ROOT)
   ```
2. Or import static object

   ```
   /commands/mycommand.py
   from django.templatetags.static import static
   url = static('myapp/myfile.txt')
   ```